# The version of xcode that supports Iphone OS 3.1.2(7D11)?

Tags: iphone

HELLO,
 I am working on XCODE 3.1.4 , my iphone have 3.1.2 os...But as this version of xcode supports iphone os3.1.1 and below.. so plz help me as  either tell me the newer version of xcode that supports iphone os 3.1.2  or should i downgrade my iphone os to 3.1.1,,

any assistance is really appreciated..

Comment: actually i was unawre of that things but now onwards....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should be using the latest version of Xcode, which is included with the iPhone SDK. You can download the SDK from the [iPhone Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action).

Comment: yup man i searched for newer version  which is 3.2 (beta version) but this version is not supported by MAC leopard 10.5.8.. so is there any other way to do that or can anyone plz tell me the rocedure to downgrade iphone os to 3.1.1..plz..

Hey tobias thanx for for early reply...

Comment: The latest version with leopard support is the iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with Xcode 3.1.4. If you click the `View:` tab marked `iPhone SDK 3.1` on the iPhone developer center you should be able to get to it. Having said that, there are some quite useful improvements in newer versions of Xcode, so you might want to consider switching to Snow Leopard if possible.